# How could I express $\sum_{n_L=0}^A\left[\sum_{n_G=n_L}^A\left((-1)^{n_G+n_L+1}\cdot\frac{p^{n_G}}{n_L!}\right)\right]$ without the sums?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Note before reading: each sum here implies its limit as the incrementing term approaches its upper bound.

> Question: How in tarnation can the constant $C$ be expressed without the sums and in terms of $A$ and $p$?
> $$C=\sum_{n_{L}=0}^{A}\left[\sum_{n_{G}=n_{L}}^{A}\left(\left(-1\right)^{n_{G}+n_{L}+1}\cdot\frac{p^{n_{G}}}{n_{L}!}\right)\right]$$

Context:

If one wanted to make an integration formula for $x^p$, where $p\in\Bbb C$, specifically by expanding the expression into the Taylor series, the steps I took to solve it are below:

1. Since: $x^p$ is identical to $\sum^\infty_{n=0}(\frac {\ln^n(x)*p^n}{n!})$
   The integral on both sides would be:
   $$\int x^pdx=\int \sum^\infty_{n=0}\biggr(\frac {\ln^n(x)*p^n}{n!}\biggr)dx$$

Notice that each term in the sum is in the form $c*\ln^n(x)$ where $c$ is a constant with respect to $x$: this is important for the second step.

2. To get rid of the integral, one would need an integration formula for $\ln^n(x)$. Using the sum formula for$\int \ln^n(x)dx$, one would get that

$$\int \ln^n(x)dx=\sum^n_{j=0}\biggr((-1)^{j+n}x\ln^j(x)\frac{n!}{j!}\biggr)$$.

3. Plugging this into the original equation, it becomes

$$\int_{ }^{ }x^{p}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{p^{n}}{n!}\cdot\left[\sum_{j=0}^{n}\left(\left(-1\right)^{j+n}\cdot x\ln^{j}\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{n!}{j!}\right)\right]\right)$$
Which, after simplifying, becomes

$$\int_{ }^{ }x^{p}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\sum_{j=0}^{n}\left(\left(-1\right)^{j+n}\cdot x\ln^{j}\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{p^{n}}{j!}\right)\right]$$

4. Notice that the only problem about this series is, despite its derivative being correct, it is divergent! OH NO!!!

After noticing that an identical series can be expressed as

$$\lim_{A\to \infty} \sum_{n_{L}=0}^{A}\left[\sum_{n_{G}=n_{L}}^{A}\left(\left(-1\right)^{n_{G}+n_{L}}\cdot\frac{x\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)^{n_{L}}\cdot p^{n_{G}}}{n_{L}!}\right)\right]$$

I noticed that in order to complete the formula, I must find constant $C$ that will,∀$A\in \Bbb R$ and ∀$p\in \Bbb C$, satisfy the following equation when $x=0$ (for simplicity):

$$0=\sum_{n_{L}=0}^{A}\left[\sum_{n_{G}=n_{L}}^{A}\left(\left(-1\right)^{n_{G}+n_{L}}\cdot\frac{x\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)^{n_{L}}\cdot p^{n_{G}}}{n_{L}!}\right)\right]+C$$

Treating the product $x\ln^{n_L}(x)$ as its limit as $x$ approaches  $0$, which is $1$,  we get that $C$ must equal the following series:

$$C=\sum_{n_{L}=0}^{A}\left[\sum_{n_{G}=n_{L}}^{A}\left(\left(-1\right)^{n_{G}+n_{L}+1}\cdot\frac{p^{n_{G}}}{n_{L}!}\right)\right]$$

Which lead me to my question, which I emphasize: how, in the world, in tarnation can the constant $C$ be expressed without the sums and in terms of $A$ and $p$?

Please provide your method of solving; thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, the inner sum can be eliminated by pulling the
$n_L$ terms out.
It then becomes a geometric sum which can be readily evaluated.

I am on my phone now, so I am not going further, except to note that it looks that the result will partial sums of the exponential series, which might be evaluable as
$A \to \infty$.

(here it the rest)

Rewriting,

$\begin{array}\\
C_n
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\left[\sum_{k=j}^{n}\left(\left(-1\right)^{k+j+1}\frac{p^k}{j!}\right)\right]\\
&=-\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{(-1)^j}{j!}\left[\sum_{k=j}^{n}\left(\left(-1\right)^{k}p^k\right)\right]\\
&=-\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{(-1)^j}{j!}\left[\sum_{k=j}^{n}(-p)^k\right]\\
&=-\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{p^j}{j!}\left[\sum_{k=j}^{n}(-p)^{k-j}\right]\\
&=-\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{p^j}{j!}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}(-p)^{k}\right]\\
&=-\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{p^j}{j!}\dfrac{1-(-p)^{n-j+1}}{1-(-p)}\\
&=-\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{p^j}{j!}\dfrac{1-(-p)^{n-j+1}}{1+p}\\
&=-\dfrac1{1+p}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{p^j}{j!}+\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{p^j}{j!}(-p)^{n-j+1}\right)\\
&=-\dfrac1{1+p}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{p^j}{j!}+\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{p^{n+1}}{j!}(-1)^{n-j+1}\right)\\
&=-\dfrac1{1+p}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{p^j}{j!}+(-p)^{n+1}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{(-1)^j}{j!}\right)\\
&\to -\dfrac{e^p}{1+p}
\qquad\text{as } n \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$